# Jenkins filtered view - enabled jobs in a failed state

Tags: regex, jenkins

I want to setup a simple Jenkins view that will show all jobs with a specific regex for the project name that are enabled and are in a failed state.

I select 'Enabled jobs only' under the Status filter section.

I select 'Failed' under the Job Statuses Filter with a match type of 'Include Matched - Add jobs that match this filter'

I use a regex of `(?!TEST).*$` to exclude any jobs that have 'TEST' in the project name.

This does not work - I get all builds that are in a failed status, even the ones that are disabled (the last build before being disabled was Failed) including the ones with 'TEST' in the name.

Any ideas on how to make this view work?

Answer (score -1):

You cannot filter jobs in Jenkins view based on their status. The regex Filter field is applicable only to Job names and the regex you entered will filter only job names containing TEST

Comment: I disagree - you can filter by status by choosing the 'Job Statuses ' filter.  What I want to do is create a view based on a job status  and a RegEx.  They seem to work separately, but not together.